# Coloring $\mathbb R^n$ with $n$ colors always gives us a color with all distances.

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math, combinatorial-geometry

I wanted to share a really cool but simple problem.

Consider a coloring of the points of $\mathbb R^n$ with $n$ colors. Prove that there is a color $c$ such that for any $r>0$ there are two points of the color $c$ at that distance.

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the following.

Assume the converse: for each color $i$ there exists a number $r_i>0$ such that there are no two points of the color $i$ at that distance. After a (re)enumeration we can assume $r_1\ge r_2\ge\dots r_n$. For each $i$ let $X_i$ be a set of points of $\Bbb R^n$ colored by color $i$.

Now we do the following inductive construction. Let $j_1=\min \{j:X_j\ne\varnothing\}$. Pick an arbitrary point $x_1\in X_{j_1}$. Let $S_1$ be a $(n-1)$-dimensional sphere with center $x_1$ and radius $R_1=r_{i_1}$. Then $S_1\subset\Bbb R^n\setminus X_{j_1}$. Suppose that $1\le i<n$ and for each $1\le l\le i$ we already build an $(n-l)$-dimensional sphere $S_l$ with radius $R_l\ge\frac {r_{j_l}}{\sqrt 2}$ and an index $j_l$ such that if $1<l\le i$ then $j_l=\min \{j: X_{j}\cap S_{l-1}\ne\varnothing\}$ and $S_l\subset S_{l-1}\setminus X_{j_l}$. Put $j_{i+1}=\min \{j: X_{j}\cap S_i\ne\varnothing\}$. Then  $j_{i+1}>j_i$. Pick an arbitrary point $x_{i+1}\in X_{j_{i+1}}\cap S_i$. Then an intersection $$S_{i+1}=S_i \cap \{x\in\Bbb R^n: |x-x_{i+1}|=r_{j_{i+1}}\}\subset S_i \setminus X_{j_{i+1}}$$ is an $(n-i-1)$-dimensional sphere with radius  $$R_{i+1}=r_{j_{i+1}}\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{r_{j_{i+1}}}{2R_i}\right)^2}.$$ From inequalities $r_{j_{i+1}}\le r_{j_{i}}$ and $R_i\ge\frac {r_{j_i}}{\sqrt 2}$ it follows that $R_{i+1}\ge\frac {r_{j_{i+1}}}{\sqrt 2}$.

At the end of the construction we obtain a zero-dimensional sphere $S_n$ (that is, a two-point set). But since the sequence $\{j_i\}$ is strictly increasing, we have $j_n=n,j_{n-1}=n-1,\dots, j_1=1$ and so $S_n\subset S_1\cap \bigcap_{i=2}^n S_{i-1}\setminus X_i \subset (\Bbb R^n\setminus X_{1})\cap \bigcap_{i=2}^n (\Bbb R^n\setminus X_i)=\varnothing$, a contradiction.

Comment: Yes, my idea was simply to start with an $n-1$ dimensional sphere of radius $r_n$, then take an $n-2$ dimensional sphere of radius $r_{n-1}$ contained by the original sphere. And at each step take a sphere with the next radius contained in the previous sphere. At the end you get a sphere of dimension $1$ with radius $r_2$, but since it is contained in all the other spheres all the points are of one color, the color with the smallest forbidden distance. Which implies there are two points on that sphere at the forbidden distance.